# How can we use Jmeter variable in groovy script

Tags: jmeter, groovy

I have extracted an element using Expath extractor and it is returning below:
Nov. 2015
However I only need the date that is 11/1/2015.

Comment: can you share the test plan configuration and the result you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this `Nov. 2015` stored as a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) called `oldDate` you can do something like:

```
vars.put('newDate', Date.parse('MMM. yyyy', vars.get('oldDate')).format('MM/d/yyyy'))
```

If everything goes well you will be able to refer the converted date as `${newDate}` where required

Demo:

[image: JMeter GRoovy convert date]

See [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how) for more tips and tricks with regards to working with dates in JMeter

Comment: I didn't get succeded. Code: `vars.put('newDate', Date.parse('MMM. yyyy', vars.get('${testxp1}')).format('MM/d/yyyy'))` and error is **2018-10-12 17:39:51,157 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException**. I appreciate your help

Comment: 1. Make sure that your `${testxp1}` variable exists and has value of `Nov. 2015` using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination. 2. Amend your code to look like: `vars.put('newDate', Date.parse('MMM. yyyy', vars.get('testxp1')).format('MM/d/yyyy'))`

Comment: Can you please help me in modifying code in a way to get Nov. 2015 to 11/30/2015?